# "meta-discussion" to be changed in the Ask Question's Title

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

When asking a question on a Stack Exchange site, there is a placeholder for the title as:

> What's your bug, feature request, or **meta-discussion** topic? Be specific.

Initially I thought the meta-discussion is about the discussion tag for meta site. But after a little investigation on that, I found a tag named [meta-discussion](/questions/tagged/meta-discussion), and later it was a synonym with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.

Since the placeholder is not causing any confusion, but if the placeholder was created based on the [meta-discussion](/questions/tagged/meta-discussion), shouldn't it now be updated based on the recent tag name?

The discussion tag's [synonym page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/synonyms) contains the details about the meta-discussion tag. Since all the per-site-meta **Ask Question** has the same placeholder in the **Title**.

[image: Ask Question]

Comment: If the placeholder is based on the required tags, shouldn't it be "...bug, discussion, feature request or support topic?"

Comment: @Cai: It was already available in the Tag's placeholder

Comment: That text isn't reference tags.  It's referencing concepts.  Those concepts also happen to have tags that correspond to them.

Answer (score -1):

> if the placeholder was created based on the meta-discussion

It was not.

> now it should be update based on the recent tag name?

Not applicable.

Comment: I'm not saying the meta placeholder is referencing the required tags because I have no idea but your examples make no sense; the site is *called* chemistry, the fact that it says "chemistry" in two different places is incidental—and doesn't hold for a bunch of other sites. The meta placeholder is in place on *all* per-site metas too so them referencing *this* meta's tour doesn't make much sense